# Apache - Different configuration after restarting service

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I can't access `origin.app` until I reboot apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`. If I go to `origin.app` I see a list of directories in `www` folder, the same as going to `localhost`.

Owner and permissions are the same between `000-default.conf` and `origin.conf`

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       Harrenhal
localhost       origin.app
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/lloople/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/origin.conf

```
<VirtualHost origin.app:80>
    ServerName origin.app
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/lloople/www/origin-cms/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Sorry for bad english and ask for more info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid putting hostnames or addresses inside the VirtualHost tag when at all possible. It creates the exact kinds of mystery problem you describe, because it relies on a DNS lookup at startup and compares the results to your active local interfaces.  Both of those things can change.

If you just care about differentiating based on the hostname requested, making both *:80 and "ServerName origin.app" is already sufficient.